# how to schedule an action using php in apache?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am developing a website where the users can opt for an option say 1. read books, 2. both read and download books. Now to download a book the user needs the administrator's permission. When the user opts for download book after approval he needs to collect the book from a given link sent to him over the email. If within 24 hours he does not collect it then he will be sent an email and if still he does not collect the book in 7 days an email will be sent to the approver. I have database in mysql where I store the details of the user and whether they have collected the book or not is stored in a flag..The problem lies with the periodic scheduling of these reminder emails. Can anybody help me?I need to know the ways to approach and how do i do it. I have XAMPP..Windows 2003 server and php 5 and mysql 5.6
thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows [**task scheduler**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596/en-us).

With Scheduled Tasks, you can schedule any script, program, or document to run at a time that is most convenient for you. Scheduled Tasks starts every time that you start Windows XP and runs in the background, and it starts each task that you schedule at the time that you specify when you create the task.

Schtasks schedules commands and programs to run periodically or at a specific time. Schtasks adds and removes tasks from the schedule, starts and stops tasks on demand, and displays and changes scheduled tasks.

Then, simply write a script that executes the code you need to execute at the given time.

Comment: Thanks @michael, I have included the file link to the home page of the server, so once anyone hits the page the script starts running. Sorry it is a pre-installed server version at my client side, and they would not let me change anything on the server machine. So although your solution was fabulous, but it had two cons, since the server is always running, I am not being able to trigger the event, and then they won't let me work on Schtasks.exe